# Undefined property: update_user::$update_model - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a noob at both PHP and codeigniter, so please be gentle.
I was messing around with this file and got this error.

Message: `Undefined property: update_user::$update_model`

Filename: `controllers/update_user.php`

Fatal error: `Call to a member function update_user_id() on null in C:.....update_user.php on line 20`

here is my code

```
<?php
class update_user extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
    function show_user_id() {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['users'] = $this->update_model->show_users();
        $data['single_user'] = $this->update_model->show_user_id($id);
        $this->load->view('update_view', $data);
    }
    function update_user_id() {
        $id= $this->input->post('did');
        $data = array(
            'userName' => $this->input->post('dname'),
            'userPass' => $this->input->post('dpass'),
        );
        $this->update_model->update_user_id($id,$data);
        $this->show_user_id();
    }
}
```

this is line 20

```
$this->update_model->update_user_id($id,$data);
```

anybody can give any pointers to what is wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: whats this `update_model` shouldn't it be `user_model`?

Comment: add your model code

Comment: Make sue you name your files and classes correct explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming  example Update_user.php and `class Update_user extends CI_Contoller {}` same applies for models in some cases

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$this->update_model->update_user_id($id,$data);
```

Should be:

```
$this->user_model->update_user_id($id,$data);
```

Also, every other place where you have used `update_model`, it should be changed to `user_model`.

This is assuming that you have only a `user_model` and no `update_model`. That's what your code shows.

Comment: guess i was gong "code-blind", i woke up next day and saw that too, thanks for helping guys....

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating the problem clearly. you are using **update_model** model which you haven't loaded in your **update_user** Controller. If this is it than load the **update_model** like this `$this->load->model('update_model');` else change the code:

```
$this->update_model->update_user_id($id,$data);
```

to

```
$this->user_model->update_user_id($id,$data);
```

Also please share your model code if there is any issue.